# How to run a Python script from another Python script in the cross-platform way?

Tags: python, blender

Here is the problem...

I'm writing very small plugin for Blender,
I have 10 python scripts, they parsing different file formats by using command-line, and I have a Main Python script to run all other scripts with proper commands...

for example, "Main.py" include:

txt2cfg.py -inFile -outFile...
ma2lxo.py -inFile -outFile...

Blender already include Python, so I can run "Main.py" from Blender, But I need it to work with both PC and MAC, and also doesn't require Python installation, so I can't use:

- execfile(' txt2cfg.py -inFile -outFile ')
- os.system(' ma2lxo.py -inFile -outFile ')
- or even import subprocess

because they required Python installation in order to run *.py files.

Sorry for language

Thanks

Comment: "and also doesn't require Python installation". Bad idea.  Just install Python.  Life is much simpler.

Comment: If you can't push anyone to install the platform, how can you push anyone to run your application?

Comment: As friendly as possible means simple, right?  That means Python is required and your main script simply does `import` to incorporate the 10 other processes.  That's simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for example, "Main.py" include:
>
> txt2cfg.py -inFile -outFile...
>   ma2lxo.py -inFile -outFile...

Two things.

1. Each other script needs a main() function and a "main-import switch".  See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts for hints on how this must look.
2. Import and execute the other scripts.

   ```
   import txt2cfg
   import ma2lxo
   txt2cfg.main( inFile, outFile )
   ma2lxo.main( inFile, outFile )
   ```

This is the simplest way to do things.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to execute a python script in a new process and you don't know where the interpreter you want is located then use the sys module to help out.

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen((sys.executable, "script.py"))
```

Though importing the module (dynamically if need be) and then running its main method in another script is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Use py2exe to bundle the interpreter with the scripts.
2. Import the modules and call the functions automatically.

Comment: Haha sorry! But you could use py2exe and py2app!

Comment: Yup! No problem! Although I haven't used it much, it is possible that py2app might require you to have a mac then compile on that. FYI